# emberjs instead of rendering component this was rendered <!---->

Tags: ember.js

i am new to emberjs and i am trying to iterate through arr and render a table with the content of elements of the array the each loop renders `<!---->` instead of rows in the table
what am i doing wrong?
here is my code:
app.js

```
arr=[{id:1,name:foo,completed:'yes'},{id:2,name:'bar', completed:'no'}]
App= Ember.Application.create();
App.Router.map(function(){
})

App.IndexRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return arr;
    }
})
App.SingleTaskComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    templateName: "components/single-task",
    tagName: ""
});

App.TasksCollectionComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    templateName: "components/tasks-collection",
    tagName: "tbody",
        actions: {
            newTask: function(){
                console.log("here");
            }
        }
 });
```

and here is the hbs code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/single-task">
    <tr {{bind-attr id=id}}>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="task" {{bind-attr value=name}} >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="completed">
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/tasks-collection">
    <tr>
        <td><button>+</button></td>
        <td>Tasks</td>
    </tr>
    {{#each model as |task|}}
        {{single-task id=task.id name=task.name completed=task.completed}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars"  id="index">
    <table>
        {{tasks-collection}}
    </table>
</script>
```

Comment: you are using quite an old version of ember; is there a special reason? if you have just started; why are not you using the latest version?

Comment: i am using v2.14.0 let me clarify my question how do i pass the model to the  components via component's template?

Comment: `bind-attr` is deprecated at 1.13. I assumed you were using some old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coding looks like you are not using ember-cli. please use it. In [this link](https://github.com/EmberSherpa/open-source-ember-apps) you can go through enormous projects which are using ember, you can learn from them how are they using it. You can even play with [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com) for easy learning. I will encourage you to follow ember [guides tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/tutorial/ember-cli/).

Regarding your question,
You need to pass the required data to components,

```
{{tasks-collection model=model}}
```

In single-task component, you can avoid bind-attr instead you can use it like

```
<tr id={{id}}>
```

Refer [deprecation guide `bind-attr`](https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_bind-attr) for more details